# Pass Type as a parameter to a function

Tags: c#, object, silverlight-3.0, memory-management

I have a dictionary object

```
Dictionary<string, Type> dict = new Dictionary<string, Type>();
```

I also have a **BaseClass** and a number of child-classes, say: **ChildClass1**, **ChildClass2**, etc.
The dictionary has values:

```
dict.Add("type1", typeof(ChildClass1));
dict.Add("type2", typeof(ChildClass2));
```

My question is - is there any way to do something like this:

```
BaseClass c = new <<get a type from the dict: dict[type1]>>()?
```

I just want to make my solution more flexible, but I'm not sure if that's possible at all.
Thanks!

Comment: As Sparkie answered, Activator can do this for you. If you only ever need one instance of each child class, you might want to look into object factories or structure maps

Comment: That's valuable advice, thank you! I'm not familiar with those concepts yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var c = (BaseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(dict["type1"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can invoke Activator.CreateInstance(type)